# deploying .war application failed on jboss7

Tags: jboss

i'm trying to deploy web application in jboss 7 
i placed the file in

```
> F:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
```

but the deployment is failed and `.failed` file generated with the following message

```
{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.websearch.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.websearch.war\".main: Failed to load module: deployment.websearch.war:main"}}}}
```

and here is the deployment scanner

```
<deployment-scanner scan-interval="5000" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir"
    path="deployments" auto-deploy-zipped="true" auto-deploy-exploded="true"/>
```

any help ?

Comment: You have to check the server log. check `F:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\logs\server.log`

Comment: it showed the same error that i mentioned in .failed file

Comment: Please post the log in the question.